# How to set SelectedItem in Xamarin picker when page opens

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I have a small project using XamarinForms and Prism MVVM.
On the settings page I save Author's ID from the Picker.
When I return to the settings page I want that Author to be selected by default in the picker.

This is my Picker in Xaml:

```
       <Picker x:Name="authorPicker" Title="Select Author" FontSize="Medium"
                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding NoteAuthors}"
                ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAuthor, Mode=TwoWay}"
                Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
```

When Author is selected I got this in ViewModel and it works fine:

```
    private NoteAuthor _selectedAuthor;
    public NoteAuthor SelectedAuthor
    {
        get { return _selectedAuthor; }
        set
        {   if (_selectedAuthor != value)
            {
                SetProperty(ref _selectedAuthor, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

In the ViewModel > OnNavigatingTo function I call the GetAuthor function which returns Author based on previously saved ID.

```
    public async void GetAuthor(int author_id)
    {
        NewNoteAuthor = await App.Database.GetAuthorById(author_id);
        if(NewNoteAuthor != null && NewNoteAuthor.ID > 0)
        {
            SelectedAuthor = NewNoteAuthor;
        }
    }
```

How can I "jump" to this Author when page opens? The assignment in GetAuthor function doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you retrieved NoteAuthors from database, you've to set SelectedAuthor by referencing one of them. Picker uses reference equality, so loading another instance of author from database in GetAuthor won't work at all. Following code solves this problem, and it also improves your code's performance.

```
NoteAuthors = await // read them from db ...
SelectedAuthor = NoteAuthors.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == author_id); // don't load it from database again.
```

Comment: is it mandatory to make the list of data as observable collection